# In TinyMce, how to change the color of the container when the editor in focus?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

To make it look like the editor is highlighted? 
The version of TinyMCE is the latest as of today, 4.3.2.

I thought it should be pretty simple. I have done my searches on SO, Google TinyMce forum. But I didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CSS, `mce-edit-focus` is the class used when the editor is active.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, you can add event handlers in the setup function for the editor.

```
setup: function(editor) {

    editor.on('focus', function(e) {
      $(e.target.container).find('.mce-edit-area').toggleClass('focused');
    });

    editor.on('blur', function(e) {
      $(e.target.container).find('.mce-edit-area').toggleClass('focused');
    });
}
```